# set binding context for custom element aurelia

Tags: web, aurelia

I want to set the binding context for my custom element.
something like

```
<my-custom-element context.bind="someproperty"></my-custom-element>
```

How can this be achieved?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to know the binding context within the component/custom element you can access it from the `bind` component lifecycle method, i.e.:

```
class MyCustomElement {
  context;
  bind(context, overrideContext) {
    this.context = context;
  }
}
```

https://aurelia.io/docs/fundamentals/components#the-component-lifecycle for my details

Comment: Actually that would be `overrideContext.parentOverrideContext.bindingContext` to get the parent binding context, which I believe is what he's trying to do. Under the hood this is also what `$parent` does

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to access the parent binding context from within a custom element, you can simply use `$parent.someproperty` in the view to go up a level. If all you need to do is access the parent you can combine this with `with.bind="$parent"` It's the other way around but it accomplishes the same thing.

Setting the binding context of a custom element in itself doesn't really make sense because that would mean you're changing the ViewModel

Comment: That's what I'm trying to do. I want the custom element to be declared in the parent view yet have different binding context which is created dynamically.

Comment: This happens automatically if you use `<compose view="./some-view.html"`></compose>`. It will inherit the binding context from the parent. If you have a regular custom element then that will always have its own binding context